# Stuck in function Switch case 'auth/operation-not-allowed'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, material-ui

//please help me with this function//
i am still newbie and still learn how to code and using React,
i try to make a validate for registration/signup menu

**"No error messaged but the function not work, always stuck in 
case 'auth/operation-not-allowed':"  newError.email = 'Metode Email dan Password tidak didukung';break;**

function Registrasi() {
    const classes = useStyles();

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    ulangi_password: ''
});

const [error, setError] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    ulangi_password: ''
})



const [ isSubmitting, setSubmitting ] = useState(false);

const { auth, user } = useFirebase();

const handleChange = e => {
    setForm({
        ...form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
    setError({
        ...error,
        [e.target.name]: ''
    })
}

const validate = () => {
    const newError = { ...error };

    if (!form.email) {
        newError.email = 'Email wajib diisi';
    } else if (!isEmail(form.email)) {
        newError.email = 'Email tidak valid';
    }

    if (!form.password) {
        newError.password = 'Password wajib diisi';
    }

    if (!form.ulangi_password) {
        newError.ulangi_password = 'Ulangi Password wajib diisi';
    } else if (form.ulangi_password !== form.password) {
        newError.ulangi_password = 'Ulangi Password tidak sama dengan Password';
    }

    return newError;
}
```

//**"No error messaged but the function not work, always stuck in 
case 'auth/operation-not-allowed':"  newError.email = 'Metode Email dan Password tidak didukung';break;**//

```
**const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const findErrors = validate();
    if (Object.values(findErrors).some(err => err !== '')) {
        setError(findErrors);
    } else {
        try {
            setSubmitting(true);
            await
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.email, form.password)
        } catch (e) {
            const newError = {};
            switch (e.code) {
                case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
                    newError.email = 'Email sudah terdaftar';
                    break;
                case 'auth/invalid-email':
                    newError.email = 'Email tidak valid';
                    break;
                case 'auth/weak-password':
                    newError.password = 'Password lemah';
                    break;
                case 'auth/operation-not-allowed':
                    newError.email = 'Metode Email dan Password tidak didukung';
                    break;
                default:
                    newError.email = 'Terjadi kesalahan silahkan coba lagi';
                    break;
            }     setError(newError);
            setSubmitting(false);
        }
    }
}**
```

//-----//

```
if (user) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />
}

console.log(user)
return <Container maxWidth="xs">
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>

        <Typography
            variant="h5"
            component="h1"
            className={classes.title}>Buat Akun Baru</Typography>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            <TextField
                id="email"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                margin="normal"
                label="Alamat Email"
                fullWidth
                required
                value={form.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                helperText={error.email}
                error={error.email ? true : false}
                disabled={isSubmitting}
            />

            <TextField
                id="password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                margin="normal"
                label=" Password"
                fullWidth
                required
                value={form.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                helperText={error.password}
                error={error.password ? true : false}
                disabled={isSubmitting}
            />

            <TextField
                id="ulangi_password"
                type="password"
                name="ulangi_password"
                margin="normal"
                label="Ulangi Password"
                fullWidth
                required
                value={form.ulangi_password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                helperText={error.ulangi_password}
                error={error.ulangi_password ? true : false}
                disabled={isSubmitting}

            />

            <Grid container className={classes.buttons}>
                <Grid item xs>
                    <Button
                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                        type="submit" color="primary" variant="contained" size="large"> Daftar</Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <Button
                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                        component={Link} variant="contained" size="large" to="/login" >Login</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>


        </form>


    </Paper>
</Container>
```

}

export default Registrasi;

Comment: Isn't it square brackets for hooks? i.e. `const { isSubmitting, setSubmitting } = useState(false);` --> `const [ isSubmitting, setSubmitting ] = useState(false);`, like you did with your other hooks

Comment: thanks sir i think its work, no Js eeror message again but the function is still not working, its stuck in this function "case 'auth/operation-not-allowed':
                    newError.email = 'Metode Email dan Password tidak didukung';
                    break;"

Comment: Well that looks like an issue with the user creation method you're using. Check the Firebase docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors and have a look at the cause/fix for the error `auth/operation-not-allowed`. If that doesn't fix it just Google the error message and see if other people have encountered and fixed that issue

Comment: okay, thanks sir, for your advice

Comment: Thanks sir, i have fix it, i havent activated sign in methode email in firebase